# how to put a datetime default value in .html.twig?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, twig

I want to put a default value in my form.

in my form.html.twig

```
{% for theme in themes%}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text">
        <label>date end</label>
        <input type="date" name="date_end" value="{{theme.getDateEnd().format('m/d/Y')}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But it's just do nothing. I tried multiple thing, same result...
I don't want to do this with a builder. I want the .html.twig way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
{{ theme.getDateEnd|date("Y-m-d") }}
```

for input date type.

In twig engine, formatting starts with `|` character.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Comment: It doesn't work. `<input type="date" name="date_end" value='{{ theme.getDateEnd()|date("m/d/Y") }}' />`
My view display mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Did you delete cache?

Comment: It sill doesn't work. But when I change `type="date"` to `type="text"`, the date appear. But I don't have the date widget.

Comment: Ah sure, input type date needs exact format (YYYY-MM-DD), see my edit now. (Didn't notice that input type)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60561/discussion-between-gura-and-mr-smith).