# Convert DateTime Object to Date input Date on Twig

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have and DateTime object that is sent from the server to my twig template in order to fill it on an Input type inside a form.

By dump(birthDate) on twig i'm getting this:

```
DateTime {#310 ▼
  +"date": "2010-02-02 18:23:50.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

I need to fill it on an Input date :

```
 <input name="birth" class="form-control" type="date" value="{{userProfile.birthDate is null ? "" : userProfile.birthDate|date("d/m/Y") }}">
```

I have tried with many formats with no success, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try by sending timestamp : ```value="{{userProfile.birthDate is null ? "" : strtotime(userProfile.birthDate->date)|date("d/m/Y") }}">```

Comment: Unknown "strtotime" function.

Comment: Maybe you should do it in your controller, set it on a variable and display this variable

Comment: `userProfile.birthDate.format('Y-m-d');` - although you should really use a symfony form and let symfony handle the conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to put a datetime default value in .html.twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650482/how-to-put-a-datetime-default-value-in-html-twig)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just had modify a little bit.

```
<input name="birth" class="form-control" type="date" value="{{userProfile.birthDate is null ? "" : userProfile.birthDate.format('Y-m-d')|date('Y-m-d') }}">
```